# Looping and writing through text files

Tags: python, loops, csv, text-files

I have multiple text files in a folder, let's say: '1.txt', '2.txt', etc.
I have a list called data that contains different arrays. The first array of the data, `data[0]`, should be written in '1.txt' and `data[1]` to '2.txt', and so on.
So far I have the following code:

```py
for files in folder:
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        data = zip(data[i])
        with open (files, "w") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t')
            writer.writerows(data)
        quit()
```

This works, such that every text file contains the data of the last array, as I'm not yet looping through the datafiles. How can I select file number `i` such that I can write the corresponding `data[i]`? I tried different things, but keep getting errors. Could someone help me out? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping trough all the data on every iteration of `for files in folder` and thus the last entry of the data array will always be the content of every txt file since the data is overwritten on every iteration of `for i in range(0,len(data)):`

If there is a set amount of data that corresponds to a set amount of files we can simplify the loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(files)):
    dataToBeWritten = data
    with open (files[i], "w") as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter='\t')
         writer.writerows(dataToBeWritten)
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `zip` makes no sense. `zip` is used to pair multiple sequence together e.g. `zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` returns `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`. Zipping a single sequence is equivalent to just using the sequence directly.

```py
for filename, row in zip(folder, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t').writerow(row)
```

should do more or less what I understand you ask for. If `data` is a list of lists of rows (rather than a list of rows) you'll have to swap `writerows` for `writerow`.